# Passing block from one method to another

Tags: ruby, proc

I need to pass a block from one method to another (I want to call `Rails.cache.fetch` with block passed to my method).

I can either add `&block` to parameter list and use that to pass it to the next method, or I can create a new block and call yield inside of it. I've wrote a short example and benchmark:

```
require "benchmark"

def with_block(&block)
  do_something 'Test', &block
end

def with_yield
  do_something('Test') { yield }
end

def do_something(string)
  "#{yield} #{string}"
end

n = 5_000_000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("&block") do
    n.times { with_block { "Yo" } }
  end
  x.report("yield") do
    n.times { with_yield { "Yo" } }
  end
end


&block   3.320000   0.010000   3.330000 (  3.340438)
yield    1.670000   0.000000   1.670000 (  1.669504)
--------------------------------- total: 5.000000sec

             user     system      total        real
&block   3.270000   0.010000   3.280000 (  3.275914)
yield    1.680000   0.000000   1.680000 (  1.682768)
```

Looks like `{ yield }` approach is much faster. Is it the right way to go? Are there any gotchas I'm not aware of because of calling `yield` inside a newly created block?

Comment: You have `Proc`, and the specialized `Proc` that is `lambda` that you can use as well.

A method is also a block, but not initially an object.  You can convert a method to become a `Method` object.

You have more choices than just the two ways to pass a block.  So I think your question is somewhat incomplete.

There are no special considerations from passing an anonymous block, other than not accessing it by name (outside of the method, that is), though Procs and lambdas are both considered "anonymous" I think.

Comment: `yield` is faster, indeed. Precisely because it's less functional. You can only call the passed block. You can't, for example, pass it on to the next method. Your test doesn't make sense, btw. `do_something` doesn't use the block.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You can pass it by calling it. `class Array; def my_map; map{|e| yield(e)} end end`.

Comment: @sawa: that's not passing. That's creating a completely unrelated block with all of the incurred (syntactical) overhead. Compare to `def my_map(&block); map(&block); end `.

Comment: @sawa: as a result, now the intermediate method is contaminated with implementation details of the underlying method (its block signature).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That was a typo, I've fixed the yield call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Always use `yield`, unless you have a good reason to explicitly reference `&block`.

See: [Why blocks make ruby methods 439% slower](https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.0/symbols/Proc/yield#annotation=4087638&line=711&hn=1)

With `&block`, you get a reified Proc on which you can do all kinds of [stuff](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html) and which you can move around. However, with a `yield` and an implicit block, you are limited to only calling the block.

By using `yield`, the interpreter can bypass all the Proc reification as it knows the developer won't be able to use it; hence it can keep just a C-level structure instead of having to set up a Ruby-level object.

Comment: I understand why yield is faster than having an explicit reference to `&block`. Is there a better way of passing a block from one method to another, expect from calling `yield` from a new block?

Comment: If you have a good justification for taking a performance hit, then you can explicitly reference `&block`. (You then just use `block.call`, instead of `yield`.) Or, another trick you could consider using is `Kernel#block_given?`: http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F -- which can be used without an explicit `&block` declaration.